# Publish a message from child to parent View

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm trying to flip the answer to this question on it's head:

[What's the idiomatic way to control a nested UIView in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240070/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-control-a-nested-uiview-in-swiftui)

And publish the events from the child (`WebView`) and subscribe in the `ParentView`.

I can pass the eventSender in the constructor of the `WebView` like:

```
WebView(eventSender: eventSender)
```

Then the `WebView` should be able to send events but how to I subscribe to the published events in the `ParentView`?

Does anyone have an elegant solution?

Ordinarily I would use `@EnvironmentObject` but these do not seem to work with `UIViewRepresentable`.

UPDATE - I've created a gist here of the issue: https://gist.github.com/mattlaver/45519a58de65a304b10acaee663b06a2

Note that my childView is a class, not a struct as it needs to inherit from NSObject to be able to use the navigationDelegate.

I want to close this view (navigate back to before it was shown when the navigationDelegate kicks in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding is the way to go, if you are looking to pass state from the UiViewRepresentable out, but you need to set it from a coordinator. For example:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var state: Int // this can be whatever type

  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WKWebView {
    let uiView = WKWebView()
    uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    self.state = 0
    return uiView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> WebView.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(view: self)
  }

  class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let view: WebView

    init(view: WebView) {
      self.view = view
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
      self.view.state = 1 // the binding will update the parent
      decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own `Binding` and pass whatever object you need, `@EnvironmentObject` or `@ObservedObject`.

Looks like `@FetchRequest` works well inside `UIViewRepresentable` (if you are using `CoreData`)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store<AppState, AppAction> 

    var body: some View {
        WebViewRepresentable(state: Binding<AppState>(get: { self.store.state }, set { _ in}))
    }
}

struct WebViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
      @Binding var state: AppState
      [...]
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/svanimpe/152e6539cd371a9ae0cfee42b374d7c4

Comment: I've tried using EnvironmentObject and ObservedObject and they work fine with my Views but with a UIViewRepresentable they always seem to be nil so I'm unable to use them in this case. That's what led me to combine as a possible solution to notify the parent that the child WKWebView is done.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this very question here: [How to access content view's elements later in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239306/how-to-access-content-views-elements-later-in-swiftui/58241037#58241037)

(I'm also the other of the accepted answer on your referenced post)

You'd basically want to set up a passed in handler, an approach that SwiftUI uses quite often (see `TextField`'s passed in handler options on various events.)

```swift
struct WebViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
  let onEvent: (AppState) -> Void

  // not sure what events you're talking about, probably `WKWebView` specific so tailor this to those needs
  fun eventReceived(event: AppState) {
    self.onEvent(event)
  }
```

Then in your parent view:

```swift
var body: some View {
  WebViewRepresentable { event in
    // handle your event
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to apply your answer to my code. The child is a class as as it needs to inherit from NSObject in order to capture navigation from the navigationDelegate. I need to close the child view on an event captured in the navigationDelegate. I've added a gist above.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's a `class` or `struct` (though you appear to be mashing `UIViewRepresentable`'s `Coordinator` in with itself. You might want to make `ChildView` a struct and have your `Coordiantor` be the `NSObject` subclass. That's why it exists ;) ) The point is, you pass in a closure from the `ParentView` to the `ChildView`, a closure `ChildView` invokes when it receives certain events.